# Hibernate Cannot Recreate Collection While Filter is Enabled

Tags: hibernate, collections, associations, hibernate-filters

Lets say that we have an entity defined as follows:

```
public class Member extends User implements Comparable<Member> {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Friends")
    @Filters({ @Filter(name = "deleted") })
    private Collection<Member> friends = new HashSet<Member>();
}
```

and have a filter named *deleted* with no parameters defined like

```
@FilterDef(name = "deleted", defaultCondition = "deleted = 0")
```

The problem arises when I am trying to add a new element to the *friends* collection of a persistent *Member* object. After committing the transaction the following exception rises.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: cannot recreate collection while filter is enabled: [domain.entity.Member.friends#98304]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:74)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:291)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. With me it was the combination of the @ManyToMany annotation with a java.util.List. It seems that Hibernate has a problem with recreating a Collection when the order might matter. I think that Hibernate does not check whether you actually put a Set or List into the Collection and therefore Hibernate checks the order.
So there are two possible ways, I know of, to solve this. Either you put an extra annotation @IndexColumn(name = "NAME_OF_THE_INDEX_COLUMN") to your Collection

```
public class Member extends User implements Comparable<Member> {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Friends")
    @Filters({ @Filter(name = "deleted") })
    @IndexColumn(name = "NAME_OF_THE_INDEX_COLUMN")
    private Collection<Member> friends = new HashSet<Member>();
}
```

or if the order does not matter to you, change the type to the interface Set.

```
public class Member extends User implements Comparable<Member> {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Friends")
    @Filters({ @Filter(name = "deleted") })
    private Set<Member> friends = new HashSet<Member>();
}
```

Hope this will help solve your problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with the component mapping.  the above solution is not working for component mapping. please let me know any other way to tackle this issue